# How to convert a mysql column type and collation at once?

Tags: mysql, sql, collation

I have a field that I want to integrate in a view lateron. Therefore I'm trying to convert the column to a `CHAR` column, and setting the collation explicit.

But I only succeeded when handling them separate, like:

works:

```
select CONVERT(somefield, CHAR(4)) FROM mytable;
select CONVERT(somefield using utf8) FROM mytable;
```

not:

```
select CONVERT(somefield, CHAR(4) using utf8) FROM mytable;
select CONVERT(somefield CHAR(4) using utf8) FROM mytable;
```

How can I combine those statements?

Comment: `CONVERT(CONVERT(somefield, CHAR(4)) using utf8)`?

Comment: What is "lateron"?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SELECT HEX(somefield), somefield ...`  In normal practice _neither_ of those converts should be needed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `CONVERT()` twice, once to change the type, then to change the collation.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(somefield, CHAR(4)) USING utf8)  FROM mytable;
```